# Change colour of background on click with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to change the background color from blue to another color on click.
This is what I've done so far but it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
<button v-on:click="dissapear" id="bluebaloon">

</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bluebaloon{
  background-color:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border-radius:50px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
el :'#app',
methods:{
dissapear: function(){
this.dissapear.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a VueJs reactivity to change a style:

```
<button v-on:click="dissapear" id="bluebaloon" :style="{ 'background-color': dissapearColor }">

...
data: {
  return {
    dissapearColor: 'blue'
  }
}
...
methods:{
  dissapear () {
    this.dissapearColor = "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this but it doesn't work, I'm new to vue so any extra info can help, thank you

Comment: Did you look at DOM element and its style for this button after clicking on it? Any errors in console?